# Heroku send mail via extern SMTP server

Tags: python, email, heroku, smtp, extern

is there any way to send a mail from python code via an external SMTP server with an app that is deployed on Heroku?
(Without using one of Herokus add-ons)

Thanks in advance
P.

Comment: Sending mails from python code is not the problem. My code works, but only locally. As soon as it is deployed to Heroku it is not sending mails anymore. As soon as it gets to the code line which is trying to set up the smtp connection the application crashes/times out.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use external SMTP providers to send email through Heroku (I do this on several of the apps I run). One thing to note, however, is that a lot of SMTP providers (Gmail, for example), will routinely block IPs from popular hosting providers (like Heroku) due to abuse.

This is a common issue that [has been documented before](https://help.heroku.com/CFG547YP/why-am-i-getting-errors-when-sending-email-with-gmail-via-smtp).

That's why Heroku [officially recommends](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp) using an email sending service like Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc. since they are dedicated email providers that are meant to be used by developers and won't block you, etc.

**In short**: your external SMTP provider is likely blocking the Heroku service. Check-in with them and see if you can either get the restriction removed or potentially used a real email sending service if you want guaranteed delivery.

Comment: Thank you so much for this profound answer.
I wasnt completely sure if Heroku maybe is entirely blocking SMTP connections to force users to use their offers.
Seems like I cannot remove this restriction from my mail provider settings.
Maybe you can let me know which provider you are using in your apps?
I would really appreciate that.
Thanks

Comment: I'm using a private SMTP server I set up myself. I used to use Gmail but had similar issues when they started blocking AWS IP ranges :(

Comment: Does anyone know an external mail provider (not one of herokus integrated modules!) that is compatible with heroku? That would be just great.

Comment: @PietZeHut there are tons. You also don't have to use SMTP for this. For example, Mailgun, Sendgrid, etc. are all independent email services. They just have a Heroku addon so you can easily create an account with them through Heroku if you want, but you don't have to. I strongly recommend Sendgrid or Mailgun as they're super easy to use and work great for sending email. You can sign up independently, get an API key, and add it to your Heroku environment variables to use it just like you would any other service.

Comment: the actual goal was to be independant from other services. Anyway thank you very much for your recommendations, thats great.